# How to add items to desired ViewHolder position when using multiple viewtypes in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-listadapter

[image]

I drew what I'm trying to implement.

To explain the function, it is a `workout log app`.

Image means that both `RoutineItem` and `DetailItem` can be `added and deleted` by `button`.

*(I didn't include a picture of a button that adds a `RoutineItem` in the image!)*

I made a function that adds both `RoutineItem and DetailItem`, but I couldn't create a function that adds `DetailItem` to each `RoutineItem` last.

In other words, when the button of each `RoutineItem` is pressed, a `DetailItem` should be added to the end of each `RoutineItem`, but my current implementation is that any `RoutineItem` button is always added to the end of the `List` when the button is pressed.

I'm not sure how to figure out the end of each `RoutineItem` because I'm implementing it using `Multiple ViewHolder`.

How do I know the last `DetailItem` listed after each `RoutineItem`?

***RoutineItem.kt***

```
sealed class RoutineItem() {
    data class RoutineModel(
        val workout: String, // excercise
        val unit: String, // unit (kg or lbs)
        var routineDetail: List<DetailModel> = listOf()
    ) : RoutineItem()

    data class DetailModel(
        val set: String,
        val reps: String = "1",
        val weight: String
    ) : RoutineItem()
}
```

***ViewHolder.kt***

```
sealed class RoutineItemViewHolder(binding: ViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    class RoutineViewHolder(
        private val binding: ItemRoutineBinding,
        private val addDetailClicked: (Int) -> Unit,
        val deleteDetailClicked: (Int) -> Unit
    )
        : RoutineItemViewHolder(binding) {
        init {
            binding.add.setOnClickListener {
                addDetailClicked(adapterPosition)
            }
        }
        fun bind(item : RoutineItem.RoutineModel) {
            binding.workout.text = item.workout
        }
    }

    class RoutineDetailViewHolder(private val binding: ItemRoutineDetailBinding)
        : RoutineItemViewHolder(binding) {
        fun bind() {
            // EMPTY
        }
    }
}
```

***Adapter***

```
class RoutineItemAdapter(
    private val addDetailClicked: (Int) -> Unit,
    private val deleteDetailClicked: (Int) -> Unit) :
    ListAdapter<RoutineItem, RoutineItemViewHolder>(RoutineDiffCallback2()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RoutineItemViewHolder {
        return when(viewType) {
            R.layout.item_routine -> RoutineItemViewHolder.RoutineViewHolder(
                ItemRoutineBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                ),
                addDetailClicked,
                deleteDetailClicked
            )
            R.layout.item_routine_detail -> RoutineItemViewHolder.RoutineDetailViewHolder(
                ItemRoutineDetailBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ViewType Provided")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RoutineItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when(holder) {

            is RoutineItemViewHolder.RoutineViewHolder -> holder.bind(currentList[position] as RoutineItem.RoutineModel)
            is RoutineItemViewHolder.RoutineDetailViewHolder -> holder.bind()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = currentList.size // footer 때문에 +1

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when(currentList[position]) {
            is RoutineItem.RoutineModel -> R.layout.item_routine
            is RoutineItem.DetailModel -> R.layout.item_routine_detail
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ViewType Provided")
        }
    }
}
```

***ViewModel***

```
class WriteRoutineViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var _items: MutableLiveData<List<RoutineItem>> = MutableLiveData(listOf())
    private val routines = mutableListOf<RoutineItem>()

    val items: LiveData<List<RoutineItem>> = _items
    
    fun addRoutine(workout: String) {
        routines.add(RoutineItem.RoutineModel(workout, "TEST"))
        routines.add(RoutineItem.DetailModel("1","3","3"))
        _items.postValue(routines)

    }

    fun addDetail(pos: Int) {
        routines.add(RoutineItem.DetailModel("1","3","3"))
        _items.postValue(routines)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Epoxy. (https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy)                                  How to use -> https://proandroiddev.com/building-complex-screens-in-a-recyclerview-with-epoxy-97845e51f4da

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the way you have handled this because these things do not belong to `ViewModel` and they belong to the `Adapter`, but in your code, you can add this function to your `ViewModel` to achieve what you want this method get the position of `RoutineViewHolder` and add a `DetailViewHolder` to end of it:

```
fun addDetailItemToEndOfRoutine(parentRoutineViewHolderPosition : Int){
  var addingPosition:Int = parentRoutineViewHolderPosition 
   for(position in (parentRoutineViewHolderPosition + 1) .. routines.size()){
    if(routines.getOrNull(position) is RoutineItem.DetailModel){
     continue
    }
    addingPosition = position  - 1
    break
   }
 //now you have found the position and you can add the detail model you want
 items.add(addingPosition + 1, RoutineItem.DetailModel("1","3","3"))
 _items.postValue(routines)
}
```

this method adds a new detail veiwholder to the end of the Routine viewholder.
you can test it directly from where you use your viewmodel and for using this method in viewholder pass this method to viewholder and in viewHolder,
set it in the onClickListener you want and pass `getAdapterPosition()` to it.